# How can I define kafka producer that will have different custom type key and value serializer as per the need?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have KafkaProducer, i have configured key and value serializer like below:

```
    props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
    props.put("value.serializer", "my custom class");
```

Now my question is how can I define producer for different class type of value serializer like :

```
    props.put("value.serializer", "my custom class1");
    props.put("value.serializer", "my custom class2");
```

For best performance its better to initialize a single kafka producer only across application. So how can I  define kafka producer that will have different custom type key and value serializer as per the need?

Comment: if props is a java.util.Properties you can not store two values for the same key. the latter will replace the former ...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have more that one serializer per Producer instance.

If you have more than one serializer, then you need multiple properties, and therefore multiple configured producer instances.

---

However, this doesn't mean there are other ways around that. Spring-Kafka offers mapping types for JSON, and Confluent supports multi-typed Avro schemas in the Java serializers.

Answer (score 0):

We can create multiple kafkaProducer's with different KEY, VALUE serializers and we can those kafkaProducers to handle

```
    @Bean
    public  Map<String, Object> producerProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"2000");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        return configProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaProducer() {
        return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producerProperties());
    }

    @Bean
    public  Map<String, Object> producerJSONProperties() {
        Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG,"2000");
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JSONSerializer.class);
        configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JSONSerializer.class);
        return configProps;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaProducer<String, String> kafkaJSONProducer() {
        return new KafkaProducer<String, String>(producerJSONProperties());
    }
```

Comment: from doc ` The producer is thread safe and sharing a single producer instance across threads will generally be faster than having multiple instances. `